# Any idea how to integrate this over the reals without using wolfram alpha.

Tags: integration, analysis, indefinite-integrals, substitution

Any idea how to integrate this over the reals without using wolfram alpha?

Your welcome to go into $\Bbb{C}$ for the integration as long as its the same result over $\Bbb{R}$

I do recognize something that sort of looks like an arc tan in there  $\int \frac{(x^2+1)} {(x^4+1)}$? any level of mathemagical trickery is fine.

Comment: You want the integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ with respect to $x$, right?

Comment: $$\frac{x^2+1}{(x^4+2x^2+1)-2x^2}=\frac{x^2+1}{(x^2-\sqrt2 x+1)(x^2+\sqrt 2 x +1)}$$
and then partial fraction?

Comment: There is a whole [video solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-49nEwGafo).

Comment: Hints for one possible way to find $I:= \int\frac{x^2+1}{x^4+1}\, dx$ for $x >0$.

Dividing top and bottom by $x^2$, we have 

$$I = \int\frac{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}{x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}}\, dx.$$ Now write $x^2+\frac{1}{x^2} = \left(x - \frac{1}{x}\right)^2 +2$ and substitute $u=x - \frac{1}{x}$. You should find that $\int\frac{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}{x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}}\, dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x - \frac{1}{x}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$. You can use this to find the integral from $0$ to $\infty$. You can then double this to find the integral over $\Bbb{R}$ if you like.

Comment: But beware, directly doing $\left[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x - \frac{1}{x}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ won't give the right answer for $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^2+1}{x^4+1}\, dx $!

Comment: @Minus One-Twelfth We need just two integrals: one on $(-\infty,0^-)$ and the second on $(0^+,+\infty).$

Answer (score 4):

Use
$$\frac{x^2+1}{x^4+1}=\frac{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}{\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^2+2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Peter Foreman gave a nice trick from the classical analysis. If you are willing to use complex analysis (in case of definite integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$), then it's easy to see, that the integrand has 2 roots of $x^4+1=0$ as simple poles in the upper half-plane: $x=(i\pm1)/\sqrt2$.

The residues can be easily calculated with the formula $g(z)/h'(z)$: 
$$
\mathrm{Res}\left(\frac{x^2+1}{x^4+1},\frac{i\pm1}{\sqrt2}\right) = -\frac{i}{2\sqrt2}.
$$

Finally, the integral (we take the countour around half-circle, arc part will go to zero):
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^2+1}{x^4+1} dx = 2\pi i\sum \mathrm Res = \pi\sqrt2
$$